# Using await inide List.AddRange C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, task

I have the following code

```
        var gamesList = new List<Game>();
        gamesList.AddRange(await GetGamesSet(endpointFirst));
        gamesList.AddRange(await GetGamesSet(endpointSecond));
```

My `GetGamesSet` method is `async` and returns a `List<Game>`. The only thing it does is query an API at a given endpoint, and then serialize the result from the API to a `List<Game>` object.

The signature of my `GetGamesSet` method looks like this:

```
private async Task<List<Game>> GetGamesSet(string endpoint)
```

Now for the question. What will happen with the 2 sequential calls to `games.AddRange()`.

**1)** Will I get 2 seprate threads that will each be used to run the `GetGamesSet()` method and **AFTER** they finish, my list will be populated in the order specified (meaning the result form endpointFirst will be added and then the result from endpoint 2)

**2)** Will I get 2 seprate threads and the final ordering of the games will be dependent upon which thread finishes faster (meaning I can get the games from the secondEndpoint first if they happen to load faster)

**3)** Or maybe both my assumptions are wrong..and I can get a mixing of both results.

PS: Do I even get 2 threads from the two awaits that I create?

Comment: What happens when you run and try it?

Comment: don't assume; do

Comment: They will execute in order, not in parallel.

Comment: The API is currently in development and at the moment, the results I get from both endpoints are mostly the same, so I cannot really determine the ordering, hence my question :)

Comment: @Evk so basically the results from the first call will be added, and then the second will start. Only real benefit I get from the current situation is that my main method is not blocked (and stucked waiting on those 2 lines of code while the execute), am I correct?

Comment: "PS: Do I even get 2 threads from the two awaits that I create?" No. Or at least, not necessarily. There may be absolutely no new threads. There may be one. There may be 2. But it's important that you understand that "await" doesn't mean "create a new thread". It means "asynchronously wait for the result" - how that happens depends on the thing you're awaiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using snippet from above like this:

```
private void Start()
{
    // blocks an execution here waiting for FillList() to finish
    FillList().Wait();
}

private async void FillList()
{
    var gamesList = new List<string>();
    gamesList.AddRange(await GetGamesSet());
    gamesList.AddRange(await GetGamesSet());

    /* more stuff */
}

private async Task<List<string>> GetGamesSet()
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    return new List<string> { "result1", "result 2" };
}
```

At the very first call to `AddRange`, FillList() will exit to the caller Start() and will block execution on Wait() method.

Meanwhile `await GetGamesSet()` will be running asynchronously and will eventually return succesfully with set of data.

Next, the control will be returned to the next `AddRange` and will wait for the result asynchronously the same way as in the first call.

When FillList finish execution, `Start()` will return.

Ordering of result is obvious from the fact, that program skips code of `async` method immediately exiting it to the caller when awaiting the called function.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the great answer. One more question tho - if I don't have the .Wait() call in the Start method, will that Start() continue with its execution until the AddRange() finishes?

Comment: Compiler will warn you about this. You could use `Start()` instead of `Wait()` but you wouldn't know when task ends.